# Error when running dropbox.py

Tags: python, dropbox

```
test@SERVER:~/source/dropbox/.dropbox-dist$ ./dropbox.py      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dropbox.py", line 39, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 30, in <module>
    from urlparse import urljoin as basejoin
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urlparse.py", line 84, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: cannot import name namedtuple
```

dropbox.py has 755 perms. In system I have `2`, `2.6` versions of python. Running `python2 dropbox.py` or `python2.6 dropbox.py` spits the same error.

and here is [dropbox.py](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) file from Dropbox website

Update per comment:

```
test@SERVER:~/source/dropbox/.dropbox-dist$ python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import namedtuple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name namedtuple
>>>
```

Comment: What happens if you try `from collections import namedtuple` in the `python2.6` IDE? And could you please post the header of that IDE session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there's another module in your Python path named `collections` (probably `collections.py` but could also be a folder named `collections` that has an `__init__.py` in it) that's preventing the Python 2.6 `collections` module from being imported. Could be something in the directory that's current when you invoke Python -- check there first. Otherwise try `python26 -c 'import sys; print sys.path'` to see where Python's looking for modules.

Comment: In my case, I had put dropbox.py in the .dropbox-dist/ folder. This was causing the error. As soon as I moved it outside the folder, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

@kindall was right. The .dropbox-dist folder contains `collections.so` which interferes with the dropbox.py script. Move the file to a different folder. Here is one way:

```
mkdir cli
mv dropbox.py cli/dropbox.py
cd cli
./dropbox.py --help
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try do to

```
python -c 'import collections; print collections.__file__'
```

And ensure that the path is `/usr/lib/python2.6/collections.pyc`. If not, then you have another modules in your PYTHONPATH that replace this one. If yes, then try again by doing:

```
python -c 'import collections; print dir(collections)'
```

And show us the result.

Normally, namedtuple have been introduced to 2.6 so...